# how can I stop activity wdeviceclick back button on my device

Tags: android, button, android-activity

Answered and trusted look comments !
Thank sania

```
  public class Test extends Activity {

HTML5WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String url = i.getStringExtra("url");  // retrieve the value you passed

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {    
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);  // use that value
    }

setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
}

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mWebView.stopLoading();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       onBackPressed();

   }

   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }

    public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Test.this, fragment_main.class);
   myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
   startActivity(myIntent);
   finish();
   return;


    }  
}
```

how can I stop last activity when clicked back button ? I was made a vimeo app working with listview how can I stop and close (vimeo videoplayer.class) that activity.when I click back button its going first activity or showing message Application was stopped :/

Comment: put classname.this.finish() in ur last activity

Comment: Ow okey this playing video am I write after return like gnrl.thisfinish () ?

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Test.this,  fragment_main.class);
   myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
   startActivity(myIntent);
   finish();
   return; Test.this.finish () -> am i write like this ?

Comment: Ya.but what exactly u wanna do on back key.u want quit apps or wanna go previous page

Comment: No quit I wanna go previous activity but this  activity will close because video still playing background and voice coming

Comment: Sorry but It's not working ?

Comment: OnDestroy() stop ur video.I mean before going to previous page..u need to stop video.

Comment: Yeaa I wanna stop video how can I do that ? Am I write on destroy () ?

Comment: Okey I will add on destroy after public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(Test.this, fragment_main.class);
   myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
   startActivity(myIntent);
   finish();
   return; ?

Comment: If dat doesnt work . call video.stop method inside backkey method

Comment: den put a useful(up arrow) to my comment :)

Comment: It's showing you can't vote up this comment maybe I'm noob xd

Comment: Now add a tick mark..u can put tick mark as noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ondestroy () or video.stop() methods in backkey method

Comment: I was selected my favourite answer but I can't vote it.its wanting up to 15 rep puan  .s